# Select right DLL referenced version at runtime

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I'm working on a mod for Mount and Blade 2 and having an issue with how it's dealing with modification.
Mods are used like plug-in and they are composed of one or a few DLLs, that can reference other DLLs.
The issue is that i reference a library NHloader version 1.0.1 in my own DLL and when testing on my own everything is perfect.
When i load with other mods it becomes a bit more messy as sometime NHloader is used by another mod and the version referenced is the 1.0.0, that lacks some of the methods i use.

So right now it's a bit random, as the first mod to load also load it's version of NHloader with no way to specify that i only want the latest version loaded. Is there a way to force this behavior? Or at least ensure that my DLL will only use the correct version or later?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Merge and internalize the version you want using tools like IL-Repack.

Comment: Lookup the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.8) which allows you to choose what gets loaded..